# Jetty Jars Upgradation

Tags: java, jetty

I'm using Jetty as my webserver. Initially I was used Jetty-8.1.9.v20130131 Version Jars. Now I'm trying to upgrade to Jetty-9.0.4.v20130625. Unfortunately some of the classes were changed in Jetty-9.0.4.v20130625. For example they deprecated `SetUIDServer` class and I don't know which class is the equivalent class in Jetty-9.0.4.v20130625.

Also `org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector` they removed this class in latest Jetty version. So how can I find the classes which are equivalent classes for the classes which were changed from version-8 to version-9.

Can some one please help me on this. I was stuck here. I was unable to proceed further.

Thanks,
Amar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the connector architecture of jetty 9 was completely refactored, you could start with the jetty.xml from jetty-9 under jetty.home/etc/jetty.xml

check out [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1419?focusedCommentId=12783478&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel) and [this](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-connectors.html)

for the deprecated class, check out the related javadoc or source code, it might come with a migration guide such as "use XXX instead"

hope this helps

Comment: I'll chime in here as opposed to a new thread on the SetuUIDServer.  I moved it to eclipse so it is under a different package for Jetty 9. See: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setuid.html#configuring-setuid